# My Discord.js bot is running (online and shows in console) but it won't respond to commands

Tags: javascript, bots, raspberry-pi3, discord.js

So, one day I was using TeamViewer to connect to my RPi3 and told it to reboot. As soon as it finished, I connected to the pi, started the bot, and it looked like it was starting up properly.

When I went to send a command on discord, the bot didn't respond. The bot is still running though.

I tried changing some of the code, but nothing changed.

Here's the code:

```
[REMOVED]
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is lack of blocking of your if statement.

```
if (message.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel)
    message.channel.send("``Beep boop! Sorry, I can't respond to direct messages, but you can join the AKAS Gamer's Discord group here: https://discord.gg/QkjQNAr``");
    return
```

With the lack of bracketing, your return will always execute as it is not part of the if statement.  It should be:

```
if (message.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel) {
    message.channel.send("``Beep boop! Sorry, I can't respond to direct messages, but you can join the AKAS Gamer's Discord group here: https://discord.gg/QkjQNAr``");
    return
}
```

Common recommendation in C-style languages is to never omit the brackets.  Get into that practice. While it is technically allowable for single statement conditionals, it will cause headaches later as you've seen here.